# Custom(different) right-click menus for node, edge and canvas in MxGraph

Tags: javascript, angular, mxgraph

I need to provide different actions/options in the right-click context menu depending on whether the user clicks on a node or an edge or on the empty canvas area.

I've been studying the drawio/jgraph source code, specifically the menus.js file to understand how the right-click menus are context specific. The draw.io app does seem to have different right-click menus on the canvas vs. the vertices & edges. However I haven't come across the code doing the differentiation of the object clicked on.

Any help or pointers on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend the `graph.popupMenuHandler.factoryMethod` functionality, let me give you a code example

Let `graph` be your **graph object**

```
graph.popupMenuHandler.factoryMethod = function(menu, cell, evt)
{
  if(cell.edge){
      menu.addItem('First edge option', null, function()
      { 
        alert('This is the first option of edge ');
      })
      menu.addItem('Second edge option', null, function()
      {
        alert('This is the second option of edge ');
      })
  }
  if(cell.vertex){
      menu.addItem('First vertex option', null, function()
      {
        alert('This is the first option of vertex ');
      })
      menu.addItem('Second vertex option', null, function()
      {
        alert('This is the second option of vertex ');
      })
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - this was simpler than the code in drawio! I had to add some closing brackets and add an addition if to handle the non-vertex and edge condition but works great. Any pointers though on how I could format the menu background colors etc.?

Comment: What would you like exactly to do? You could edit `src/js/util/mxPopupMenu.js` `addItem` function to set your own styles, if you have more questions please post a new question :)

Comment: Well since the rest of the app is built in Angular8+Bootstrap4, the context menu in mxGraph looks rather out of place compared to the rest of the dropdown menus. So just wondering how I could bring some parity in styling. No worries, will do some more digging and post a new question if needed :). Thanks a lot!